# How to remove the error message from <video> in win8 app? (html/js)

Tags: javascript, html, video, windows-8

How can I disable the left-bottom error message within the video element in a win8 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to provide a bit more information about what exactly are you trying to do ? 
As of now, I think providing the correct video source will help  with removing the error message.

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
        <source src="Videos/abc.mp4" type="video/mp4" />    
</video>
```

Where Videos is a folder in the project package and abc.mp4 is the video file inside the Videos folder.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: My problem is that I get the videos from the web and sometimes the path is broken and I have my own error message for that so I don't need an another message.